# Minimum PHP version for running Magento Web Service APIs

Tags: php, web-services, magento, version, magento-1.4

Can anybody please suggest how to know the minimum PHP version, for working of the Magento v1.4.x.x Web Services?

**EDIT:-**
My problem is that I am trying to run an API Web Service (having tried both V2 & normal SOAP) for downloading Store Lists. But nothing is returning, no error, no display nothing. I have also tried with run-time configurations (using in-built function "`ini_set()`"), but in vain:-

- soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 0
- soap.wsdl_cache_ttl = 0
- display_errors = 1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try looking through http://www.magentocommerce.com ?

Comment: You can find requirements there http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements but it's for v 1.5.xx else you can try to launch this script http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

Comment: @Marc B, @j_freyre - yes, all of these have been checked. Only confusion is that whether these requirements suffice for the Web Services also?

Comment: just run the latest PHP Version, why would you want to run an older version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP version requirements [listed on Magento's site](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements) for PHP (5.2.13+) should be used for the latest releases.  As far as the Web Services, as long as the PHP version requirements are met, and the [SOAP module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) is installed and enabled you shouldn't have any problems. For previous versions like 1.4.x.x, the last entry from [way back machine](http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20090306094647/http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements) shows 5.2.0+ So it would safe to assume the latest 5.2.x of PHP will work.